# python Mechanize ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpacky

Tags: python, mechanize

can some one help me out ?
this is my code :

```
from mechanize import Browser
import re


user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7$'
br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(False)
br.addheaders = user_agent 

req = br.open("https://google.com")
date = req.read()
```

and this error that i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "vpnbook.py", line 12, in <module>
req = br.open("https://www.google.com")
File "/home/grimm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize   
/_mechanize.py", line 254, in open
return self._mech_open(url_or_request, data, timeout=timeout)
File "/home/grimm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize
/_mechanize.py", line 284, in _mech_open
response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
File "/home/grimm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize     
/_opener.py", line 190, in open
req = meth(req)
File "/home/grimm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize     
/_urllib2_fork.py", line 1104, in do_request_
for name, value in self.parent.addheaders:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpacky
```

im using python 2.7 and Ubuntu 18.04 bionic.

Comment: Aren't you missing a second `'` at the end of your string? If this did just accidentally happen when posting the code here you should fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote   Anthony Sottile 
>   tnx for helping it worked